# Why is Rails changing the case of initial letter of words in my text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I display strings in my UI, Rails 3.2 is changing this:

"10020 Main Street"

to

"10020 main street"

How do I avoid this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some context? Where you get those from, the view file excerpt?

Comment: you might have a method calling `.downcase` on this string somewhere in a helper.

Comment: or maybe a css rule with "text-transform: lowercase"?

Comment: @JuLiu so true, a css could be too...

Comment: I believe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264307/why-is-rails-not-displaying-strings-that-end-in-a-period will answer and close this question

Comment: Sorry about that. The data is a string field in the database table, and it is a field in a model. There are no methods that process the data. Just retrieve the data from the database and display it. The data is saved correctly in the database. Once again, sorry if I assumed to much, but this seemed so basic. I'll see if I have any CSS that might be changing the data.

Comment: Wrapped it in a <span>. Sorry for being boneheaded. Thanks for your responses.