# Why is Rails not displaying strings that end in a period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

If I save this string to an address field:

11060 Westmoor Dr.

It doesn't display in the UI.

But if it saved without the period at the end,

11060 Westmoor Dr

Then is does display in the UI.

Why does the period cause the string not to display?

I'm displaying it like this:

```
<%= f.label "#{user_event.address1}, ", class: 'info_label' %>
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264053/why-is-rails-changing-the-case-of-initial-letter-of-words-in-my-text  Are you kidding? how people are suppose to guess why it does this and that if you do not provide anything to debug? address1 is an attribute? or this is a method in a model?

Comment: Sorry about that. address1 is a string field in the database table, and it is a field in a model. There are no methods that process the data. Just retrieve the data from the database and display it. The data is saved correctly in the database. Once again, sorry if I assumed to much, but this seemed so basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using a label in this manner. The label should be used as a field name. So, rather than output the string of someone's address, you should use it like:

```
<%= f.label :address_line_1 %>
<%= f.text_field_tag :address_line_1 %>
```

Rails is removing punctuation here because you can't have "." as method names

Comment: I see. Thanks for your response. I was using a label, because I don't need a label per se for the field, meaning I don't need this:     Address1 11060 Westmoor Dr.     I just need to display the address value. I had thought if I used a text field then I would need to make it uneditable, because this is a display page, not an edit page. In any case, thanks for your responses, and a lesson learned.

Comment: if this is a display page why using f.label and not `<%= @user_event.address1 %>`

Comment: to display the value of address1, you should `<%= @user_event.address1%>`.

Comment: Yep, just figured that out. Wrapped it in a <span>. Sorry for being boneheaded. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: We've all been beginnings befor, no apologies for taking an approach. Please mark this answer as correct.